# OAuth: Re-issue same access token on refresh

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am implementing an oauth server using spring oauth. I notice that spring's implementation re issues the same access token if not expired from the token endpoint. However the behavior is different while refreshing access tokens. A new token is reissued each time, are there any concerns to keep in mind if I were to reissue the same un expired access token on receiving a valid refresh request.

Answer (score 0):

The [OAuth Spec section-6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) specifies that:

> The authorization server MAY issue a new refresh token, in which case
> the client MUST discard the old refresh token and replace it with the
> new refresh token.  The authorization server MAY revoke the old
> refresh token after issuing a new refresh token to the client.  If a
> new refresh token is issued, the refresh token scope MUST be
> identical to that of the refresh token included by the client in the
> request.

There does not seem to be a requirement that the access token is brand new.

I think the main concern is to ensure that you do not change the expiration date on an existing token. And that you correctly return to the client an accurate `expires_in` property which reflects when the token will expire.

In addition, it might make the semantics confusing for clients. The refresh is usually done when a token is expired, and the client wants a new one.

I can imagine some odd edge cases. A client could send a request to refresh a token a few seconds before it is expired (perfectly valid logic for a client), but still receive back the same token which is almost expired.

Comment: I would like clients to pre-fetch access tokens before the actual expiration.

Comment: In that case, you should probably issue new tokens on refresh, otherwise clients would not be able to pre-fetch.